# Business objects and multiple data sources

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, design-patterns

On my WPF application, I made two separate projects: the UI (with the XAML and the ViewModels) and the "Core" (it has what people call "domain objects" or "business objects" - objects that represent discrete concepts in my use cases). I understand this is a good practice.

But many of my business objects interact with multiple data sources. For example, a `Document` object might contain data from the database as well as from a file.

And then, some of the things you can "do" with `Document` - which I implement as methods on `Document` - involve other resources. For instance, `Document.SubmitForProcessing()` calls a web service.

So I wrote this:

```cs
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileData { get; set; }

    private Document() { }

    public static Document GetByID(int documentID, string databaseConnectionString, string baseFilePath)
    {
        // Using Dapper
        Document newDoc = db.Query<Document>("SELECT Name, FilePath FROM Documents WHERE ID = @pID", new { pID = documentID });

        newDoc.FileData = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(basePath, newDoc.FilePath));

        return newDoc;
    }

    public void SubmitForProcessing(IWebService webService)
    {
        webService.ExecuteFoo(this.Name, this.FileData);
    }

    public void DoBusinessStuff()
    {
        this.FileData = this.FileData.Replace("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this got super annoying really fast and it's sort of difficult to write tests against it.

So I read about dependency injection and the repository pattern. But I'm not sure how to do it correctly in this scenario. Do I have separate repository classes for each data source, and then some kind of `DocumentFactory` or something that accesses the separate repositories and stitches together a Document object? Or is there a simpler way?

My main concern is to make the code test-friendly so I can write some unit tests without mocking up an entire database and filesystem, but also to stop passing a whole smorgasbord of parameters to each and every factory method that I have (e.g. `GetByID(int documentID, string databaseConnectionString, string baseFilePath)` - my real life ones have over half a dozen parameters like this).

On similar questions, the answers talk about things like SOLID, YAGNI, repositories are for CRUD, etc. I value those principles, but I'm having trouble getting the practical design from them. For instance, the web service isn't really CRUD-y. Do I have a "repository" for it so that I can switch it out during unit tests? What about for the filesystem?

TL;DR - what's wrong with that code?

Guidance appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods and I/O functions are naturally hard to test if you do not use some advanced unit test tools (for example Stubs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798446.aspx). The problem you are facing is that you have a static method calling two I/O functions. The goal is to decouple them.

The first thing I would do is to refactor your GetById method to a Factory class. You can create your factory class by passing the database and file system I/O implementation as interfaces. 
The advantages of using interfaces is that it allows you to mock the I/O behavior. For the simple interfaces like I did below, I can even simply implement them in my test code without any mocking. In this way, you can isolate the business logic of the GetById method to your Factory class, and you will not bother testing the I/O itself, as it is done by the database provider and win32 api. This is all your need.

```
class Document
{
    public string FileData { get; set; }
    public string FileRelativePath { get; set; }
}

interface IDocumentRepository
{
    Document Get(int id);
}


abstract class  DocumentFactory
{
    public abstract Document Create(int docId);
}

interface IFileStore
{
    string Read(string fileName);
}

class ConcreteDocumentFactory : DocumentFactory
{
    private IDocumentRepository _db;
    private IFileStore _fileStore;

    public ConcreteDocumentFactory(IDocumentRepository db, IFileStore fileStore)
    {
        _db = db;
        _fileStore = fileStore;
    }

    public override Document Create(int docId)
    {

        Document newDoc = _db.Get(docId);
        newDoc.FileData = _fileStore.Read(newDoc.FileRelativePath);
        return newDoc;
    }
}


/////// Test Code Below

[TestFixture]
class TestClass
{

    class TestFriendlyFileStore : IFileStore
    {
        public string Read(string fileName)
        {

            if (fileName == "sample.txt")
                return "Some File Content";
            throw new Exception("Not good file name.");
        }
    }


    class TestFriendlyDocRepo : IDocumentRepository
    {
        public Document Get(int id)
        {
            if (id != 999)
                return new Document() {FileRelativePath = "sample.txt"};
            throw new Exception("Not good id.");

        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var concreteDocFactory = new ConcreteDocumentFactory(new TestFriendlyDocRepo(), new TestFriendlyFileStore());
        var doc = concreteDocFactory.Create(999);
        Assert.AreEqual(doc.FileData == "Some File Content")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the last answer, is only suitable to test your business classes and  catch only expected exceptions from infraestructure, database or web services calls only on client code, so i would suggests you to desing software that is infraestructure agnostic in order to have it SOLID and Testable:

```
public class Document : IAcceptDocumentVisitor
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public string FileData { get; private set; }

    public Document(int id, string name, string filePath, string fileData)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        FilePath = filePath;
        FileData = fileData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method replace SubmitForProcessing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="visitor"></param>
    public void Accept(IDocumentVisitor visitor)
    {
        if (visitor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(visitor));
        visitor.Visit(Name, FileData);
    }

    public void ReplaceFileData(string fileData, Action onSuccess)
    {
        //Business valdation 
        var validate = true;
        //Business valdation 
        if (!validate) return;
        FileData = fileData;
        onSuccess();
    }
}

public interface IAcceptDocumentVisitor
{
    void Accept(IDocumentVisitor visitor);
}
public interface IDocumentVisitor
{
    void Visit(string name, string fileData);
}

public class FakeWebServiceVisitor : IDocumentVisitor
{
    public void Visit(string name, string fileData)
    {
        Name = name;
        FileData = fileData;
    }

    public string FileData { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WebServiceVisitor : IDocumentVisitor
{
    public void Visit(string name, string fileData)
    {
        //Call web service
        //webService.ExecuteFoo(this.Name, this.FileData);
    }
}

public interface IDocumentReader
{
    Document GetById(int id);
}

public class DocumentDbReader : IDocumentReader
{
    public Document GetById(int id)
    {
        //Get from database
        //Document newDoc = db.Query<Document>("SELECT Name, FilePath FROM Documents WHERE ID = @pID", new { pID = documentID });
        return new Document(id, "Name", "Path", "Data");
    }
}
```

Usign some OOP techniches and patters such as repository, visitor, CQRS, and solid, you can have benefits such as SOLID code and you will start to make your code testable as well:

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentSpecs
{
    public string Name = "Name";
    public string FilePath = "Path";
    public string FileData = "Data";
    [TestMethod]
    public void AcceptVisitorCorrectly()
    {
        //Arrange
        var document = new DocumentDbReader().GetById(0);
        var visitor = new FakeWebServiceVisitor();
        //Act
        document.Accept(visitor);
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(FileData, visitor.FileData);
        Assert.AreEqual(Name, visitor.Name);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReplaceFileDataCorrectly()
    {
        //Arrange
        var successActionCalled = false;
        var expectedFileData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var document = new DocumentDbReader().GetById(0);
        //Act
        var documentInitialData = document.FileData;
        document.ReplaceFileData(expectedFileData, () => successActionCalled = true);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(successActionCalled);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedFileData, document.FileData);
        Assert.IsFalse(documentInitialData == document.FileData);
    }    
}
```

Here are the results:

[image: Test results]

Kind Regards!